# Getting email and Microsoft Teams notifications twice when Spring boot admin server is setup as a 2 node cluster

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I created a 2 node Spring boot admin server cluster as described here https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#clustering-support

The Spring boot app I have is getting registered once and shows up with the same instance ID in both the spring boot admin servers. However, the email notifications and Microsoft Teams notifications are being sent out twice anytime the status of the app changes. Is there some setting to prevent this?

Comment: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/1122 I see that it is an existing limitation. Hopefully, it is fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is an existing issue. There is an enhancement request opened for it.
https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/1122